# How to write command for Kubernetes pod with flag and parameter on same line?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, yaml, openshift

I have this configuration working for a Kubernetes/OpenShift cronjob/pod:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: activate-trigger
    image: curlimages/curl
    command:
      - curl
      - --header
      - "content-Type: application/json"
      - --data
      - '{"name": "Pipeline triggered from curl"}'
      - http://api.endpoint
```

I would like to combine the flag and it's associated value on to the same line with something along the lines of:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: activate-trigger
    image: curlimages/curl
    command:
      - curl
      - --header "content-Type: application/json"
      - --data '{"name": "Pipeline triggered from curl"}'
      - http://api.endpoint
```

But I could not find the right combination of quotes and double quotes to get it working. Is this possible to do in YAML and Kubernetes?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible.  There might be a workaround if the tool, e.g. `curl` can accept `=` in their flags.  Per this post: https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/how-to-write-command-for-kubernetes-pod-with-flag-and-parameter-on-same-line/26071